# Upload XBee firmware without a PC and XCTU

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, xbee, firmware

So, as the title suggests, I would like to know if there is a way of uploading a firmware to a XBee module, throug the serial without a PC. What I mean is, I have a microcontroller, I would have the firmware file(s) stored in some kind of memory (like an SD card, flash...) and directly upload this firmware through serial without the need to get assistence from a computer.

I don't really know if this is possible, I don't hink it is, but it would be great for my project if it was! :) So, since I didn't find anything relevant on this matter, maybe one of us had experienced this and/or tell me with certainty that it is or is not possible!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on something where I'll need this eventually, but it'll probably be a few weeks until I get around to it. What I was planning to do was use the following utility to look at the protocol used by XCTU, you might be able to use it to get a few ideas: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the firmware upload protocol is known a micro-controller can do this. But with a quick google I did not find a description of this protocol, so this might be a problem. Hardware-wise the interface is just a serial connection.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain better, but yes, I understand how the microcontroller would have to act, so my question is enhanced by @PeterJ comment. For your statement that "Hardware-wise the interface is just a serial connection", sure, but XCTU also only need to see the serial pins in order to upload the firmware. So I guess the poiny here is get a way of unreaveling the protocol, so we could put a microcontroller to execute it, instead of XCTU.

Comment: Take care to ask what you really want to ask! As your question is formulated now, the answer is simply YES. That does not help you if what you are after is a description or better yet a SW-implementation of the protocol.

Comment: By answering simply YES you would be telling me that you know for sure, authoritatively, that without a doubt, that IS possible. So, I guess you succeeded doing it and would care to explain how? That would be very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Knowing that it can be done is not the same as having done it. A protocol can always be re-engineered, either from logs or from reading the application code. The interesting question is whether someone has already done this (or maybe the manufacturer has published it).

Comment: I've being searching for this and I don't think the manufacturer has published it.